# Item not visible in horizontal scrollable container

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar

I'm trying to make navbar scrollable horizontally, so I set

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

As you can see here:

[image: navbar]

I can't reach "Men" dropdown, what could cause that ?

Comment: Can you show how is your HTML too?

Comment: Oh, it was because of `justify-content: center`. Thank you anyway.